# Restricting access in my client application using the email domain within the JWT

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, jwt, supabase

I am wondering if there is any security issues i am overseeing by restricting access in my web-application in React based on their email domain. The email is extracted from a JWT, which is stored in the local storage in the browser.

My code looks something like this:

```
function AuthenticatedRoutes() {
  const { session } = useAuth() as AuthContextType;

  if (!session) {
    return <Navigate to="/auth" />;
  }

  if(session.user.email?.split('@')[1] === 'domain.com'){
    return <Navigate to="/admin" />;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
}

export default AuthenticatedRoutes;
```

For context i am using the supabase.js client library and their Auth API.
Basically what i am trying to achieve is to differ out "normal" authenticated users and "admin" authenticated users.

I know that another way of doing this is adding custom claims to the JWT. however, on the client side, it would be handled pretty much the same way.
The question is; is there any way for the user to manipulate this email?

Please let me know if i am missing something

Answer (score 0):

The JWT security is based on the signature of the JWT token. The user can manipulate the token in any way (s)he wishes, but after the manipulation, the signature no longer match the contents. And with robust cryptographic algorithms (like HSxxx), there's no feasible way for the user to generate a new signature for the modified token.

So, as far as I can understand, your method is as robust as using claims, as long as external users have no way to create an account with *domain.com* -email.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My thoughts exactly :)